# Does work function of photoelectric effect follow conservation of energy?

Tags: electrons, energy-conservation, spectroscopy, photoelectric-effect

If an electron receives the right photon, it gets excited and emits another photon or multiple less energetic photons when it returns to ground state. Therefore energy is conserved.
However, if an electron receives enough energy (referred to as work function) to be kicked out of the orbitals, it can not return to ground state and emit photons. So where did the energy go?

Answer (score 1):

In that case the electron absorbs the energy of the incident photon (which will be greater than the amount of the work function). So the energy after this interaction would be contained in the scattered electron. So

$$E_{\gamma} = K_e + \phi$$

where $E_{\gamma}$ is the energy of the incident photon, $K_e$ is the kinetic energy of the ejected electron and $\phi$ is the work function or the minimum energy required to liberate the electron.

So conservation of energy certainly holds.

Answer (score 1):

Electron releases the work function energy to be bound to metals again.